# ie7-js causing double vertical spacing

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

Test site: http://wfwgm.stage.philosophydesign.com/

I have included:

```
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script>
```

to give :before support in IE6 and IE7 but after loading that up I'm getting strange behaviour.

If I use IE9 in compatibility mode (IE7) it appears that ie7-js is not working. If I fire up IETester and load the site in IE6/7/8 ie7-js is working but everything on the page is double spaced vertically.

[image: Extra spacing]

So there is two questions here really.

> 1. Why is ie7-js not working in IE9 in compatibility mode?
> 2. Why when ie7-js is working everything is double spaced vertically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find the reason why this was in the end, but I did find a solution. I was using ie9.js but didn't need the features from it. So I switched down to ie8.js. Upon doing this the double margins fixed themselves.

Answer (score 0):

As for the double vertical spacing, i could see from your test site code that your  element has a top and bottom margin set to 1em for IE7. When i turned this off from the browser (F12 in IE), the double vertical spacing was gone.